# Liquibase alternative for PostgreSQL Update-From?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to alter a couple related tables to simplify them after some design features got outdated: namely, I have a **clients** table with a **passwords** table; where each client can have multiple passwords (not exact case but mimicks the relationship the same way).

For some reason, when these tables were originally created, a UUID was used as pk for each table, but the clients also have each a unique code, so the **clients** table looks like this

| (client) id | code | other data.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a4ffc8be-13a4-4e4d-b243-00dc373a591c | CODE_A | ... |
| de34a0da-9bca-4b1f-a3bc-5d853fc52268 | CODE_B | ... |

while the passwords table looks like this:

| (password) id | client | other data.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9c1c9d57-ca3e-4990-9461-5e6cca3d1acc | a4ffc8be-13a4-4e4d-b243-00dc373a591c | ... |
| 8c7bfb7e-2ff0-4fc1-b0af-804d803c611b | de34a0da-9bca-4b1f-a3bc-5d853fc52268 | ... |

So, I'm trying to juggle out of that situation, replace the PK on the clients table for the code, drop the "id" column, replace the FK on the passwords table from column "id" to "code" and update the value appropriately. Resulting passwords table would look like:

| (password) id | client | other data.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9c1c9d57-ca3e-4990-9461-5e6cca3d1acc | CODE_A | ... |
| 8c7bfb7e-2ff0-4fc1-b0af-804d803c611b | CODE_B | ... |

for updating the value I figured I can use this:

```
UPDATE PASSWORDS
   SET client = CLIENTS.code
   FROM CLIENTS
   WHERE CLIENTS.id = PASSWORDS.client
```

But I would rather avoid adding a raw `<sql>` to our liquibase files for consistency, if there's a supported alternative.

Much appreciated for any input!

PS: for reference, this is a java Spring Boot project using
`org.liquibase.liquibase-core:3.8.9` and
`org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.19`

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in a database independent manner. A `<sql>` is the easiest and probably also the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Will [this update format](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/update.html) help in some way? I could not think of a command.

Comment: I don't think so sadly, I think I will need to just use raw sql